# How to use Google Analytics Embed API in Electron JS

Tags: electron

Is it possibile to use GA Embed API in Electron JS?

I looked for NPM's, but I can't see any related to it.

I've copied the example from here:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/

and added it to my electron project.

I'm getting this error: **yw {message: "Invalid cookiePolicy", stack: "gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError"**

That's why I'm not sure if it's possible to use the Embed API in Electron.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and congrats your first post. But wish question should be more specific.

Comment: @tpikachu thanks for the suggestion. I've edited the post.